# Setup Cucumber, Capybara and RSpec with Modular Sinatra application

Tags: rspec, cucumber, sinatra, capybara

Here's my `config.ru`

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'config')
require 'boot'

Routes = Rack::Mount::RouteSet.new do |set|
  set.add_route App::Users, { :path_info => %r{^/users*} }, {}, :users
  set.add_route App::Dashboard, { :path_info => %r{^/$} }, {}, :dashboard
  set.add_route Rack::File.new(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public"), { :path_info => %r{^/*} }, {}, :public
end

run Routes
```

`boot.rb`

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
Bundler.require(:default)
Mongoid.load!(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/mongoid.yml'))
%w(sinatra json yaml rack/mount rack/contrib).each {|l| require l }
Dir["./lib/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
```

And my `lib` contains the apps and the models.

How to let Cucumber to see my application:

here's cucumber `env.rb`

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rspec'

World do
  Capybara.app = App
  include Capybara
  include RSpec::Expectations
  include RSpec::Matchers
end
```

What I want is to let env.rb read my config.ru and get my cucumber ready for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set your `env.rb`:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'config/boot.rb')

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.app = eval("Rack::Builder.new {( " + File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config.ru') + "\n )}")

class SomeWorld
  include Capybara
  include RSpec::Expectations
  include RSpec::Matchers
end

World do
  SomeWorld.new
end
```

And It'll work!

Answer (score 15):

In @amrnt's solution you can replace that line

```
Capybara.app = eval("Rack::Builder.new {( " + File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config.ru') + "\n )}")
```

with this:

```
Capybara.app, _ = Rack::Builder.parse_file(File.expand_path('../../config.ru', __FILE__))
```

or

```
Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.parse_file(File.expand_path('../../config.ru', __FILE__)).first
```

Comment: `Rack::Builder.parse_file` — exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks, that got my Capybara tests working after refactoring my app into modular controllers. Question: Why does `Capybara.app, _ = Rack::....` work and `Capybara.app = Rack::....` not work? What does the `, _` do???

Comment: Comment size is restricted heavily... so tl;dr - in Ruby, and other languages, the convention is to use `_` when something is returned to you, that you don't need to assign. For instance: `def foo; "bar", "baz"; end`. Apologies for no block syntax highlighting. If you don't need "baz" assigned, use `qux, _ = foo`. If you do need both, do `qux, quz = foo` as normal. It's the same thing here. [`.parse_file` returns two objects](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb#L45) so if you don't need the second object, you'd use `_`. This also happens with block args a lot.